# Do we need to Recompile all stored procedures when indexes rebuild happen?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Recently I have done rebuilding indexes on my production server.
Do I need to re compile all my existing stored procedures to get this effected.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you should recompile the stored procedures (you can use [sp_recompile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181647.aspx)).  Changing the table structure forces a new execution plan, but just adding an index does not.  When you restart Sql Server, that will have the same effect.

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190439.aspx):

> As a database is changed by such
>   actions as adding indexes or changing
>   data in indexed columns, the original
>   query plans used to access its tables
>   should be optimized again by
>   recompiling them. This optimization
>   occurs automatically the first time a
>   stored procedure is run after SQL
>   Server is restarted. It also occurs if
>   an underlying table that is used by
>   the stored procedure changes. But if a
>   new index is added from which the
>   stored procedure might benefit,
>   optimization does not occur until the
>   next time that the stored procedure is
>   run after SQL Server is restarted. In
>   this situation, it can be useful to
>   force the stored procedure to
>   recompile the next time that it
>   executes

Comment: Would that apply to rebuilds too, though?

Comment: Thanks a million Kevin, can you provide some msdn articles on this.

Comment: Check the link on "From MSDN".  That should link to the article.

Comment: @JNK according to the article I would say yes as rebuilding the index is necessary due to data changing in the table.

Comment: @JNK - No it won't. Rebuilds will automatically update stats with full scan anyway so you get an optimality based recompile due to updated stats. I don't think the quote in this answer is correct anyway. It is contradicted by other pieces of documentation and testing. I've raised [a connect item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/809771/recompile-a-stored-procedure-topic-contains-incorrect-assertion) to ask for the discrepancy to be reviewed.

Comment: @JNK - Confirmed the documentation is incorrect and will be updated.

Comment: You should probably delete this as docs have been updated. It's just not true (any more? perhaps at some point it was)

Answer (score 1):

Your question was about "rebuilding indexes" but the quote in the answer you accepted is about creating new indexes.

Rebuilding indexes will also end up re-creating the statistics on that index with fullscan.

As a result of the updated statistics all affected queries will automatically get an optimality based recompile. Except if the query happens to contain the `KEEPFIXED PLAN` hint.

Moreover I don't believe the quote in Kevin's answer to be correct (at least since SQL Server 2008+) anyway.

Both of the following white papers state that "Adding an index to a table or an indexed view" *will* cause a recompile.

- [Plan Caching in SQL Server 2008](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee343986%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)
- [Plan Caching and Recompilation in SQL Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn148262.aspx)

This is also what I see when testing.

```
CREATE TABLE T(X INT, Y INT);

GO

CREATE PROC P AS SELECT Y FROM T;

GO

EXEC P;

GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX ON T(Y);

GO

EXEC P;


GO


DROP TABLE T;DROP PROC P
```

The execution plan shows the new index is used automatically

[image]

Profiler shows an automatic recompile with reason "Schema Changed"

[image]